# problem with p2os teleop

Tags: ros, p2os

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have pioneer 3-AT robot. It connected my notebook with serial to usb cable.
ROS fuerte has installed in my notebook with Ubutu 11.10.
I installed p2os referred to p2os_tutorial.

When I launch the p2os teleop_keyboard, it works well, but pioneer doesn't move.
The motor is fully enabled with p2os_dashboard. p2os teleop_joy has the same problem.
The pioneer beeps only..in regularly.

Could you give me a help?

---

- roscore

```
jhp@ubuntu:~$ roscore
... logging to /home/jhp/.ros/log/5d906d6c-d7c3-11e1-9b40-001d728c5b11/roslaunch-ubuntu-19950.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is
```

- Run the p2os_driver

```
jhp@ubuntu:~$ rosrun p2os_driver p2os 
[ INFO] [1343377049.882478998]: using serial port: [/dev/ttyUSB0]
[ INFO] [1343377049.904677981]: P2OS connection opening serial port /dev/ttyUSB0...
[ INFO] [1343377050.313218974]: SYNC0
[ INFO] [1343377050.513818710]: turning off NONBLOCK mode...
[ INFO] [1343377050.714331842]: SYNC1
[ INFO] [1343377051.114779904]: SYNC2
[ INFO] [1343377051.715227279]: Done: Connected to Samtronics3233, a Pioneer p3at-sh
[ INFO] [1343377054.118100925]: resetting raw positions
</code></pre>
- Run teleop_keyboard
<pre><code>jhp@ubuntu:~$ roslaunch p2os_launch teleop_keyboard.launch 
... logging to /home/jhp/.ros/log/5d906d6c-d7c3-11e1-9b40-001d728c5b11/roslaunch-ubuntu-21208.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is
```

-rostopic list

```
jhp@ubuntu:~$ rostopic list
/aio
/base_controller/command
/battery_state
/cmd_motor_state
/cmd_vel
/diagnostics
/diagnostics_agg
/dio
/gripper_control
/gripper_state
/joy
/motor_state
/p2os_teleop/cmd_vel
/p2os_teleop/des_vel
/p2os_teleop/joy
/pose
/ptz_control
/ptz_state
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/sonar
/tf
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39962/problem-with-p2os-teleop/) by [Park](https://answers.ros.org/users/2931/park/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2012-07-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks that /cmd_vel should be connected to /p2os_teleop/cmd_vel to make it work.
You can verify the connection by using rxgraph command.
If they are not connected, you can remap the topics to solve it.

Another typical problem with keyboard teleop nodes is that they require the focus on the corresponding terminal window. Otherwise, the key strokes are not received by the node.

---

Originally posted by [Pablo Urcola](https://answers.ros.org/users/545/pablo-urcola/) with karma: 188 on 2012-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RafBerkvens](https://answers.ros.org/users/4316/rafberkvens/) on 2013-03-20**:
This is also true for the ROSARIA package, where /cmd_vel should be remapped to /RosAria/cmd_vel.